# How do I get the internet speed that of a hosting company?

Tags: networking, hosting, performance

I own a popular website, heavy on traffic and space.

I can't solely trust my hosting company with backups, plus - hardware is expensive to rent. So I am looking into hosting the website in-house. I called my ISP to set up a connection, the price is right, but maximum they can do is 50Mb/sec. I need at least 200Mb/sec and more in the future.

How do hosting companies do it? Do I purchase 4 separate connections and somehow route them into one server? Or do I have to rent an office in a specific area? I'm in the Tacoma, WA area, if it matters. How do I get the speed that of a hosting company?

I'm hoping with something around $1000/month.

Comment: UNfortunately, as much as I sympathise with your situation, this question is shopping related and incredibly localised, and as a result, we can't really help you here. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: P.S. As WesleyDavid says, for $1000/month you can easily move your server into someone elses datacenter and get a gigabit link, assuming you have a rack mounted server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the speed of a hosting company, you need the infrastructure of a hosting company. That means, find a co-location environment and rent however many U you need to rack up your server(s). They will have the kind of bandwidth you need up to gigabits per second. Fortunately, it sounds like your budget is reasonable. Do a search for "Tacoma colocation" and you should find what you're looking for.

P.S. You'll never be able to do this in your own home.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I'm going to do!

Comment: And the word itself "colocation" helped a lot. Now I get the right search results.

Answer (score 1):

That 50 Mb/s limit is just your ISP's doing - either they don't have the capacity to carry more, or their delivery mechanism to your location is limited to that speed - what you're looking for is definitely possible, just apparently not in your current ISP's service scope.

Shop around - you may need to pay for some fiber trenching to your location if existing media won't cut it, but a provider should be able to provide you with as large of a handoff as you need for the right price.

Comment: I'm only limited to Comcast. Will I need to pay for so many miles of fiber to my house? That would seem way out of my budget.

Comment: @Tim Oh.. you meant "in-house" rather literally!  Yeah, Comcast won't help you.  I'd recommend looking at co-location providers, instead; bring your own hardware and rent some space in a location where you can get a high speed handoff from a provider with a lot less fuss.